# Conflict resolution in Android's SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

How does Android's SQLite library resolve conflicts if I insert duplicate rows? I am building my app for API level 7, which unfortunately does not have the `SQLiteDatabase.insertOnConflict()` method that was included starting in API level 8.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can specify a [UNIQUE](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint) index in the table definition which will allow rows to be [REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)D:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
)
```

If a row an INSERT or UPDATE statement tries to add a row with an id which already exists, the existing row is replaced with the new one.

Comment: +1 Potentialy dangerous, but also useful feature I haven't heard about befor.

Comment: Indeed, you must be careful and ensure it is the desired outcome in all cases. It works great for things like syncing a local database with remote data.

Comment: Thanks. This will work for now. But, as I understand it, if I create a table with this declaration, it will do a replace every time there's a conflict. But what if I don't want to use this kind of conflict resolution each time I do an insert?

Comment: Oh wait, never mind, the other answer answered that question for me.

Comment: If the other answer is answered, you can accept the other answer always. Why not doing that?

Comment: The important point to read in the doc here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html  is.. "The algorithm specified in the OR clause of an INSERT or UPDATE overrides any algorithm specified in a CREATE TABLE. If no algorithm is specified anywhere, the ABORT algorithm is used."

Comment: I think you should write query for replace , that will update if already exist else insert new record.

Comment: This doesn't work: `CREATE TABLE t (id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, UNIQUE (id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE); INSERT INTO t VALUES(1); INSERT INTO t VALUES(1);`. Use `CREATE TABLE t (id  INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);`

`AUTO INCREMENT` and `ON CONFLICT REPLACE` don't work together

Answer (score 6):

There's a `ON CONFLICT` clause in SQLite that you can say `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT...`.

Read the documentation please.  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Comment: Indeed, use this if you don't always want to replace on conflict.

Answer (score 0):

By default i you have unique index exception will be thrown on duplicated index insert. Common solution is check record existence before execute insert - pseudo-code:

```
select * from people where name = 'Smith';
//if resultset is empty then perform insert
insert into people values 'Smith'
```